# 'System.Net.WebClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering' is obsolete'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is the full error

> Error 1   'System.Net.WebClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering' is obsolete:
>   'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your
>   code.'    C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\C#\AutoClicker\AutoClicker\Form1.Designer.cs    128 13  AutoClicker

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iqzI1fu.png]

[image]

**Everytime I make any change to my designer form, I get this error. Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Comment: If you create a new form, and just drag a WebClient onto it, and make no other changes, do you get this error on the new form?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Nope! And I just tried messing around again to try and get the error but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things I would try:

1) Delete the webclient and add it back in to see if that fixes it.
2) Define the webclient in code instead of through the designer.
3) Check your References to see what version of System.net you are using. i.e. if it is any older .net version