# Downloader not working

Tags: vb.net, coding-style, savefiledialog, webclient

```
Imports system.net
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub cmdsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdsave.Click
        SaveFileDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        ''"EXE (*.exe) |*.exe |JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg | MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3 | WAV (*.wav) |*.wav ";
        SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.Text = SaveFileDialog.FileName
    End Sub
    Public WithEvents download As WebClient
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        download = New WebClient
        download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(TextBox1.Text), TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub download_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles download.DownloadProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to make a downloader but I keep getting an error with the SaveFileDialog area. I am a newbie with VB.Net and I'm wondering what i need to change to make it work and successfully download all type of files.

Comment: You should fix the error in the SaveFileDialog area

Comment: Telling us the error you're getting is a very good start.

Comment: well i add `Dim objSaveFileDialog as New SaveFileDialog()` and now i only get two codes

Comment: There errors are `Public Overloads Property AllowReadStreamBuffering As Boolean' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.` I clicked on them and it lead me to two `Me.WebClient1.AllowReadStreamBuffering = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have declared SaveFileDialog as a SaveFileDialog then I believe your error is related to a non-shared member. This is not causing your error though.

One suggestion, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020747/system-net-webclient-allowreadstreambuffering-is-obsolete), says to remove the webclient and readd it to your form.

Also, one quick(dirty?) fix is to target a lower version of the .Net Framework under your Application Properties.

Either of those should do the trick for this issue.

Comment: These are all the errors that I got when I tried to run the program. And will  ` "All files (*.*)|*.*" ` work to save all type of files

Comment: Error BC30668 'Public Overloads Property AllowReadStreamBuffering As Boolean' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'. Guillermo's Downloader C:\Users\The Orange Box\Desktop\Not Porn\Guillermo's Downloader\Guillermo's Downloader\Form1.Designer.vb 106 Active

Comment: Error BC30668 'Public Overloads Property AllowWriteStreamBuffering As Boolean' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'. Guillermo's Downloader C:\Users\The Orange Box\Desktop\Not Porn\Guillermo's Downloader\Guillermo's Downloader\Form1.Designer.vb 107 Active

Comment: I have drastically modified my answer as providing the error greatly changes what I assumed was causing the problem.